# Thirdweb Connect Wallet button: can we modify its size?

Tags: thirdweb

As the title describe, I cannot be able to change its size, is it possible?

It seems it is hard coded as 200x50 and it has no props to change it!

Answer (score 0):

hey @xyz you can pass a `className` to it to give it styles. (you may need to do `!important` in your CSS styles.

Make sure you're on the latest version of the SDK, which should be 3.5.1

You can also wrap the ConnectWallet button with a div with a fixed width.